# Invalid parameter number when executing query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query a values and if there is a `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` table `person`. But I am getting an error `Invalid parameter number'`. This causes the query to not work at all. `personal_id` is the unique identifier in order to properly execute the `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. How can I fix this invalid parameter number in my query? [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/test/select_test.php)

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //Insert or Update Values 
    $f = 1;
    while(isset($_POST['person_fname_' . $f])) {
        $person_fname = $_POST['person_fname_' . $f];
        $person_lname = $_POST['person_lname_' . $f];
        $personal_id = $_POST['person_id_' . $f];

        $query_init3 = "INSERT INTO person (person_id, academy_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (:personal_id, :id,:person_fname,:person_lname) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE academy_id=:id, first_name=:person_fname, last_name=:person_lname";
        $query_prep3 = $db_con->prepare($query_init3);
        $query_prep3->execute(array(
            "id" => $id,
            "personal_id" => $person_id,
            "person_fname" => $person_fname,
            "person_lname" => $person_lname
        ));
        $f++;
    }   
}
```

HTML

```
<ul id="pq_entry_1" class="clonedSection">

    <li>
        <input id="person_fname_1" name="person_fname_1" placeholder="Person #1 - First Name" type="text" />
    </li>

    <li>
        <input id="person_lname_1" name="person_lname_1" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" />
    </li>

    <li>
        <input id="person_id_1" name="person_id_1" type="text" />
    </li>

</ul>

<input type='button' id='btnAdd' value='add another Person' />
<input type='button' id='btnDel' value='delete Delete' />
```

Comment: try to add not 3 params but all of them with different names

Comment: @VitKos Can you explain? Not sure what you mean. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry, try to make bind variables not the with the same name.

Comment: @VitKos okay, I did but no changes :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the same bound param twice, u need to specific a new one

```
$query_init3 = "INSERT INTO person (person_id, academy_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (:personal_id, :id,:person_fname,:person_lname)
                  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE academy_id=:id2, first_name=:person_fname2, last_name=:person_lname2";
$query_prep3 = $db_con->prepare($query_init3);
$query_prep3->execute(array(
    "id" => $id,
    "personal_id" => $person_id,
    "person_fname" => $person_fname,
    "person_lname" => $person_lname,
    "id2" => $id,
    "person_fname2" => $person_fname,
    "person_lname2" => $person_lname
));
```

Comment: Actually, you can use it several times in the query and bind just one parameter as long as it is a named parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `:` before each parameter:

```
        $query_prep3->execute(array(
            ":id" => $id,
            ":personal_id" => $person_id,
            ":person_fname" => $person_fname,
            ":person_lname" => $person_lname
        ));
```

This is not very intuitive but is explained in the docs: http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: It made no difference with the semicolon.

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student You must use it anyway.